# Problem in civicrm upgrade 4.74 to 4.7.5 in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, upgrade, 4.7, mysql

When I Intented upgrade my site from civicrm 4.7.4 to 4.7.5 in drupal 7 one error appear and don't is possible continue. (sorry for my english)

Could yo help me with this error?

This is the error screen

---

[Error: Upgrade DB to 4.7.5]

```
Campo de error  Valor de error
Type    DB_Error
Code    -1
Message DB Error: unknown error
Mode    16
UserInfo    CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_events_in_carts_after_insert after insert ON civicrm_events_in_carts FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF ( @civicrm_disable_logging IS NULL OR @civicrm_disable_logging = 0 ) THEN INSERT INTO log_civicrm_events_in_carts (id, event_id, event_cart_id, log_conn_id, log_user_id, log_action) VALUES ( NEW.id, NEW.event_id, NEW.event_cart_id, CONNECTION_ID(), @civicrm_user_id, 'insert');END IF; END [nativecode=1235 ** This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table']
DebugInfo   CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_events_in_carts_after_insert after insert ON civicrm_events_in_carts FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF ( @civicrm_disable_logging IS NULL OR @civicrm_disable_logging = 0 ) THEN INSERT INTO log_civicrm_events_in_carts (id, event_id, event_cart_id, log_conn_id, log_user_id, log_action) VALUES ( NEW.id, NEW.event_id, NEW.event_cart_id, CONNECTION_ID(), @civicrm_user_id, 'insert');END IF; END [nativecode=1235 ** This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table']
PEAR_Exception: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown
- DB_Error: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown
```

Exception Trace

```
Function    -- Location

0   CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error)) --   unknown:unknown
1   call_user_func(Array, Object(DB_Error))     -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:931
2   PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error('DB Error: unknow…', -1, 16, Array, 'CREATE TRIGGER c…')     -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php:976
3   DB_Error->DB_Error(-1, 16, Array, 'CREATE TRIGGER c…')  -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:564
4   PEAR->raiseError(null, -1, null, null, 'CREATE TRIGGER c…', 'DB_Error', true)   -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php:1905
5   DB_common->raiseError(-1, null, null, null, '1235 ** This ver…')    -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php:895
6   DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()     -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php:328
7   DB_mysql->simpleQuery('CREATE TRIGGER c…')  -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php:1216
8   DB_common->query('CREATE TRIGGER c…')   -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:2438
9   DB_DataObject->_query('CREATE TRIGGER c…')  -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:1627
10  DB_DataObject->query('CREATE TRIGGER c…')   -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:335
11  CRM_Core_DAO->query('CREATE TRIGGER c…', false)     -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:1268
12  CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery('CREATE TRIGGER c…', Array, true, null, false, false)    -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:2105
13  CRM_Core_DAO::createTriggers(Array, null)   -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:1964
14  CRM_Core_DAO::triggerRebuild()  -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/I18n/Schema.php:348
15  CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::rebuildMultilingualSchema(Array, '4.7.5')     -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php:390
16  CRM_Upgrade_Form->processLocales('/var/local/drupa…', '4.7.5')  -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php:421
17  CRM_Upgrade_Form->processSQL('4.7.5')   -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php:663
18  CRM_Upgrade_Form::doIncrementalUpgradeStep(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext), '4.7.5', '4.7.4', '4.7.5', '/tmp/civicrm-pos…')   -- unknown:unknown
19  call_user_func_array(Array, Array)  -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php:88
20  CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext)) -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php:214
21  CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(true)     -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:52
22  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()    -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php:106
23  CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))    -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:54
24  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()  -- unknown:unknown
25  call_user_func(Array)   -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:278
26  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array)     -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:86
27  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array)     -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:54
28  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)  -- MY_PATH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module:454
29  civicrm_invoke('upgrade', 'queue', 'ajax', 'runNext')   -- unknown:unknown
30  call_user_func_array('civicrm_invoke', Array)       -- MY_PATH/includes/menu.inc:527
31  menu_execute_active_handler()      -- MY_PATH/index.php:21
32 {main}
```

Comment: How I will need continue with the upgrade I droped the triggers in the Backup DB in refered table "civicrm_events_in_carts" before to run the upgrade again  and the upgrade running OK. I supouse that the process intented CREATE the triggers but don't check if this triggers are created

Comment: The same error ocurred when upgrade from 4.7.5 to 4.7.6 without drop the triggers in table "civicrm_events_in_carts", if droped the update running ok

Comment: Then I continue the upgrade from 4.7.6 to 4.7.7 and from 4.7.7 from 4.7.8 and I don't need drop the triger any more.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL error message ({[nativecode=1235 ** This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table']}) indicates that you are probably on an outdated version of MySQL.

Can you please type the command 'mysql -V' (capital V) and report here the version number that is displayed?